# How does a stakeholder verify transactions?

Tags: proof-of-stake

Maybe I'm a bit tunnel-visioned at this point, but I am trying to get a technical grasp of how a Proof of Stake algorithm works.

I understand that a validators are chosen semi-randomly based on the amount of coin they are staking. Then 128 validators have to "attest" to each (shard) block. But once a validator is chosen, what actually happens during the validation / verification process? According to [The Motley Fool](https://www.fool.com/investing/stock-market/market-sectors/financials/cryptocurrency-stocks/proof-of-stake/)

> Since proof of stake doesn't require validators to all solve complex equations, it's a much more eco-friendly way to verify transactions.

If it's not solving "complex equations", what is it doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, transaction verification and block froming for PoW and PoS are no different. The main message of the PoS is that the stake owners are not interested in disrupting the functioning of the network and therefore it is possible to replace the resource-intensive methods of identifying a random miner among all nodes with more "economical" methods of identifying a random miner among the stake owners.

Comment: So the process of finding a nonce that creates a hash with "x" many zeros is still happening? The only difference being the process of choosing a validator (miner) is more economical?

Comment: As an option - yes

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Can you clarify?

Comment: For example, the larger your effective stake, the smaller the number of zeros the hash you should look for to form a block. Accordingly, the owner of a larger stake is more likely to create a block